# How do I loop an input box one additional time if criteria is not met?

Tags: vba, loops, inputbox

I’m trying to create a series of input boxes that will prompt for more information before executing the rest of the code.

I’m stuck on the looping aspect.

The first input box is for a **start date**. Valid entries will be a 6-digit numeric value only (unless there’s a less fussy way to prompt for a date). If “999999” is entered, the macro would skip the next input box (for the end date).

I’d like to leave a little room for user error, so if they type “01012021” or “01/01/21” or “p010121” I’d like the input box to loop one time before exiting the sub.

I tried executing this code and my Excel froze up and crashed.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim sdate As String, edate As String

DOS_all = False

sdate = InputBox("Enter the first DOS you'd like to search for:" & Chr(10) & "(enter in 6-digit format. e.g., 010121)" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Enter '999999' to search ALL available AHI data.", "Date of service begin", "999999")
   
Do
    If sdate = "" Then
        MsgBox "User canceled or did not enter any data. Macro will end.", , "User canceled"
        Exit Sub
        If sdate = "999999" Then
            DOS_all = True
            Exit Do
            If Not IsNumeric(sdate) Or Len(sdate) <> 6 Then
                MsgBox "Enter the date as 6 digit number ONLY (eg. 010121)", , "Invalid entry"
            End If
        End If
    End If
   
Loop Until IsNumeric(sdate) And Len(sdate) = 6

If DOS_all = False Then 
    edate = InputBox("Enter the last DOS you'd like to search for:" & Chr(10) & "(enter in 6-digit format. e.g., 123121)" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Enter '999999' to make end date today..", "Date of service end", "999999")
End if

Do
    If edate = "" Then
        MsgBox "User canceled or did not enter any data. Macro will end.", , "User canceled"
        Exit Sub
        If edate = "999999" Then
            edate = Date
            Exit Do
            If Not IsNumeric(sdate) Or Len(sdate) <> 6 Then
                MsgBox "Enter the date as 6 digit number ONLY (eg. 123121)", , "Invalid entry"
            End If
        End If
    End If
   
Loop Until IsNumeric(sdate) And Len(sdate) = 6

End Sub
```

Comment: [The answers to this question may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430765/input-box-date-range-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Use a separate method to gather the date, to avoid repeating similar code.

You can go easy on your users and allow them variations, as long as the entry is unambiguous.

```vb
Sub test()
    Const SPROMPT = "Enter the first DOS you'd like to search for:" & vbLf & _
           "(enter in 6-digit ddmmyy format. e.g., 010121)" & vbLf & vbLf & _
           "Enter 'all' to search ALL available AHI data."
    
    Const EPROMPT = "Enter the last DOS you'd like to search for:" & vbLf & _
           "(enter in 6-digit ddmmyy format. e.g., 123121)"
    
    Dim sdate As String, edate As String
    
    sdate = UserDate(SPROMPT, "Date of service begin", "all")
    
    If Len(sdate) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "User canceled or did not enter any data. Macro will end.", , "User canceled"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf sdate <> "all" Then
        edate = UserDate(EPROMPT, "Date of service end", Format(Date, "ddmmyy"))
        If Len(edate) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "User canceled or did not enter any data. Macro will end.", , "User canceled"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print "start", sdate
    Debug.Print "end", edate


End Sub

Function UserDate(msg As String, title As String, def As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, dt
    Do
        dt = InputBox(msg, title, def)
        dt = Trim(LCase(dt))      'trim and lower-case
        dt = Replace(dt, "/", "") 'remove any /
        dt = Replace(dt, "-", "") 'remove any -
        If dt = def Or dt Like "######" Then
            UserDate = dt
        ElseIf dt Like "########" Then
            'be nice to your users and just reformat what they gave you...
            UserDate = Left(dt, 4) & Right(dt, 2)
        End If
        If Len(UserDate) > 0 Then Exit Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < 2
End Function
```